# Change Keras Standard Deviation of Gaussian Noise Layer while training

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, gaussian

What is the fastest way to change the standard deviation of a Gaussian noise layer in Keras during training?

Currently I am reloading the whole network with the adapted  standard deviation every iteration, which is really slow.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using keras backend variables?

```
from keras import backend as K

self.std=0.5
self.std_var = K.variable(value=std)
```

When building the network.

```
# instantiate
stddev = std_var(0.8)
g = GaussianNoise(stddev)
```

During training (possibly inside a loop).

```
K.set_value(stddev.std_var, <new_std_val>)
```

Try this snippet and see whether it works.